# How to detect if a player is wearing a piece of armor with a custom model data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to detect if a player is wearing a custom armor piece to then give them an effect, up to now I have gotten to the point were I can detect the armor piece but not the custom model data:

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={abilities:{flying:0b},FallFlying:1b},nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:elytra"}]}] run say detected
```

This is the item:

```
/give @p minecraft:elytra{CustomModleData:phanom_glider} 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `CustomModelData` as `CustomModleData` in the 2nd command.

And you don't seem to have a check for the `CustomModelData` in your first command, perhaps you should include one?

```
Inventory:[{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:elytra",tag:{CustomModelData:1}}]
```

Additionally, the `CustomModelData` is an integer tag, not a string, perhaps check your setup?